# Time.zone is nill in ruby 1.9.2 -p290

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When i am trying to use Time.zone.now it gives me an error which shows that Time.zone is nill because i did not mentioned config.time_zone in my environment file and when i am doing , my server is not getting started and giving me an error.

**initialize_time_zone': Value assigned to config.time_zone not recognized.Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding appropriate time zone names. (RuntimeError)**

I am using 
rails -v Rails 2.3.11
ruby -v ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]
rvm -v  rvm 1.6.23 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.11)
actionpack (2.3.11)
activerecord (2.3.11)
activeresource (2.3.11)
activesupport (2.3.11)
archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
bluecloth (2.1.0)
builder (3.0.0)
columnize (0.3.4)
escape (0.0.4)
fastercsv (1.5.4)
hpricot (0.8.4)
linecache19 (0.5.12)
mime-types (1.16)
mysql (2.8.1)
nokogiri (1.5.0)
pr_geohash (1.0.0)
rack (1.1.2)
rails (2.3.11)
rake (0.8.7)
RedCloth (4.2.7)
rsolr (0.12.1)
ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25)
ruby-debug19 (0.11.6)
ruby_core_source (0.1.5)
sunspot (1.2.1)
sunspot_rails (1.2.1)
will_paginate (2.3.15)

Thanks
Nishant

---

If we are not mentioning the Time.zone in the environment file , it will be UTC by default. I have mentioned config.active_record.default_time zone as :utc and this was working fine in ruby 1.8.7 but when i have changed that to ruby 1.9.2 its causing problems.

Comment: What value did you define for your time zone? Do as rails recommends and use one of the output of `rake -D time`.

Comment: I did that i tried to add a time zone in environment file it gives me initialize_time_zone': Value assigned to config.time_zone not recognized.Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding appropriate time zone names. (RuntimeError) error so i removed it , but if you do not mention config.time_zone in your environment file it will take UTC as default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set explicitly your time zone in you config file if you want to use `Time.zone`. There seems to be no default value.

In `config/environment.rb`:

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
    config.time_zone = 'UTC'
end
```

To get a list of all available time zones with their UTC offset run

```
rake time:zones:all
```

Comment: I did that i tried to add a time zone in environment file it gives me initialize_time_zone': Value assigned to config.time_zone not recognized.Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding appropriate time zone names. (RuntimeError) error so i removed it , but if you do not mention config.time_zone in your environment file it will take UTC as default

Comment: Your wrote the same comment as above ... intendedly? What value did you put in your `config/environment.rb` file for `config.time_zone`? You _cannot_ leave it empty if you want to use `Time.zone`!

Comment: What are the time related changes in ruby 1.9.2 from ruby 1.8.7 ?

Comment: I don't know about any changes in time stuff. Btw: you did not answer to my comment above ...

Comment: if you do not mention config.time_zone in your environment file it will take UTC as default right ? before upgrading it was working but once switched to ruby 1.9,2 it is causing errors.

Comment: I do not have ruby 1.9.2 so I cannot answer this, sorry.